# why we use return true or false in appDelegate?

Tags: swift4.1

In this method what is the means of true and false?

```
application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: -> Bool{

 return true
}
```

if I write `return true` application Launch and works fine  either I write `return false` application work's fine.
so what is the mean of return true and false?.

Answer (score 2):

As of official documentation.

> Return Value
>
> false if the app cannot handle the URL resource or continue a user
>   activity, otherwise return true. The return value is ignored if the
>   app is launched as a result of a remote notification.

---

> The return result from this method is combined with the return result
>   from the application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method to
>   determine if a URL should be handled. If either method returns false,
>   the URL is not handled. If you do not implement one of the methods,
>   only the return value of the implemented method is considered.

For more details see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application

Comment: Hi Bilal Means you want to say that app is not open by URL schema, deep linking. and by third-party app will not open an app.

Answer (score 2):

If you return false in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` then operating system will know that you cannot open the url coming in the `launchOptions` dictionary.

There is no other use of returning value in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.